# How Can I test the joint significance of the variables not selected?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, f-test

I started a multiple regression with 10 predictors. I checked the linearity assumption and the significance of the model and now I have just 4 predictors but I have to test the joint significance of variables that were not selected. How Can I do that? I think that using F test and comparing the unrestricted model with the restricted model could be a good option. What do you think about?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I would say the F test is the default way to do what you are asking. But I am curious what is your intention by testing the collective significance of discarded predictors.

Comment: I'm using STATA. I'm talking about   F = ((SS Residual restricted – SSR unrestricted ) /(df restr – df unrestr)) / (SSR unrestr/ (n-k-1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrestricted Model: $y_i = \beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^{10} \beta_j x_{ij} + \epsilon_i$

Restricted Model: $y_i = \beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^4 \beta_j x_{ij} + \epsilon_i$

The test is $H_0: \beta_j=0$ for $j=5,6,....,10$. Either F-test or likelihood ratio test will suffice. In R, likelihood ratio test is simple:

```
um<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10,data=data1)
rm<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=data1)
summary(lrtest(um,rm))
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.